# How can I remove the header from Pandas sav?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I remove the header in the `pd.read_spss()` command in python?

```py
df = pd.read_spss("/Users/..../econ.sav")
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean remove the headers? `.sav` files are binary files with headers hardcoded. Do you mean you want to change the header names?

Comment: Do you want to avoid adding the `/Users/username/path/to/file/` part to the path?

Comment: My dataset contains a header.I want to remove it but the pd.read_spss command does not have any argument header. Like pd.read_csv